# Azure website returns 404 error after adding custom domain

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404

I'm using the Azure Websites hosting in shared mode. After going through the process of adding a custom domain I seem to be getting a 404 when browsing to `www.mydomain.example`

When I browse to my site using the `*.azurewebsites.example` address it renders perfectly. I have also turned on all available logging and can't see the 404 errors in the web logs or any other signs of the problem.

To configure the custom domain name I followed instructions on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=a%2Cazurecli) page, including setting up the CNAME record to `awverify.mysite.example` and an A record to the IP address provided in the portal.

I know there are other questions on Stack Overflow, but none of them provide an answer that fits my HTTP 404 issue. Also many of the questions on Stack Overflow seem to be out of date not that azure websites support domain names in shared mode (I believe)

Comment: Don't see any reason for closing the question. it is a `software development` issue `within the scope defined in the FAQ`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**I had only added `mydomain.example` in the azure portal and needed to add `www.mydomain.example` as well.**

I could swear that I saw some help text in the portal saying that domains should be input in that format though.

Comment: Where do you add www.domain.com in the portal?

Comment: Hi @MattKim, you need to be running the website in Shared or Standard mode first, not in Free mode. Then you will get a manage domains button appear in the configure section of the website settings in the azure portal. See here for more details: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/

Comment: Thank you man! This really helped, I just add one row (TXT) in my DNS records and validate the DOMAIN from Azure and it worked.