# Azure CNAME redirect doesn't work

Tags: azure, dns, cname

For the first time I'm trying to set up a web site on Azure and got DNS problem.
Followed this tutorial http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/

Here are my DNS records:
[image]

2 days have passed, DNS already propagated:
http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.reinspire.ru&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=

But Azure keeps saying that no record found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem "solved". It took Azure more than 72 hours to propagate DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is your issue as I'm seeing a 404 on your custom domain. [Azure website returns 404 error after adding custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469422/azure-website-returns-404-error-after-adding-custom-domain)

Comment: No, this isn't same problem, because Azure portal rejects any domain I'm trying to add, no matter with or without www

Comment: Try deleting the awverify.reinspire.ru CNAME. You should only need one for www.  See the comments section on the Azure page you linked on setting up a domain for an Azure website.